# JPA Criteria API with several parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have this code in my system in order to get users logged in to the system. Its in sql format with using createNativeQuery in Hibernate. I want to get this done with criteriaBuilder since createCriteria is deprecated. How can i do this giving both username and password to match with the database values? Thanks in advance.

```
String sql = "Select id from login where username=:username and password=:password";
Query query = session.(sql);

query.setParameter("username", login.getUsername());
query.setParameter("password", login.getPassword());

String rs = query.getSingleResult().toString();
return rs;
```

I coded until this. But syntax is wrong when trying to give multiple conditions.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Login> criteria = builder.createQuery(Login.class);
    Root<Login> employeeRoot=criteria.from(Login.class);
    criteria.select(employeeRoot);

   criteria.where(builder.equal(employeeRoot.get(login.getUsername()), "username"));
```

Comment: Just take a looh at [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/query-criteria/Criteria.html), in "Selecting an entity" section, you will find the answer. Hope this might help you.

Comment: Criteria parameters are demonstrated in this link http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/query.html#_criteria_api_parameters

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
criteria.where(builder.and(builder.equal(employeeRoot.get("username"), login.getUsername()),
                           builder.equal(employeeRoot.get("password"), login.getPassword())));
```